# Cygwin run multiple commands at once

Tags: windows, matlab, ssh, cygwin, system-calls

MATLAB runs on a host machine. By using the 'system' call and CYGWIN I have to run some applications on a remote system based on linux.
The problem is, after calling the SSH command the other commands are ignored

so

```
system('C:\cygwin64\bin\bash  -l -c "ssh -t -t 10.0.0.127; cd /home/superuser/MAGIC_PATH")
```

does not work

So I tried to change the directory sequentially after the SSH-Connections, but now the MATLAB-script is blocked. And I have to type the command manually. Which is not the desired solution

In MATLAB:

```
cygwin_path='C:\cygwin64\bin\bash';
binary_path='/home/superuser/MAGIC_PATH';
SSH_string=sprintf('%s -l -c "ssh -t -t %s &"',cygwin_path,remote_IP)
ChangeDIR_string=sprintf('%s -l -c "cd /home/superuser/"',cygwin_path)
```

So how can I change my code respectively the system call, so that it automatically runs multiple commands and starts some applications (as background jobs)

Comment: With the first system command, you probably need to add an ampersand at the end and also put the ssh command in quotes (double-delimited in MATLAB): `system('C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l -c "ssh -t -t 10.0.0.127 ''cd /home/superuser/MAGIC_PATH; <other cmds here>''" &')`